# How to keep fluid simulation level from rising

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to make a fluid-water simulation, where the ball (effector) comes from underneath the water, penetrates through the water and makes a major splash. But once the effector comes through the water, the water simulation starts rising within in the Domain cube. I want it to remain in its initial position. which settings do I need to tweak?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's pretty weird. I can only assume it is a bug. Did u try filing a bug report?

Comment: or maybe it is "just" a rounding problem. I just raised the resolution to 64 and i got [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfv2L.png -> so maybe "just" a high resolution will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `Initial Velocity` for `Source` on the "Fluid Liquid" mesh was set at 1. Changing it to 0 stopped the water from rising.**

This is what yours was set at:

[image]

This is what I changed it to:

[image]

Comment: if this really solves the problem, i would report it as a bug because initial velocity wasn't checked and shouldn't influence anything (and with "geometry" there should no velocity at all). I just tried it out and my result with Blender 3.4 looked like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WV6X.png ...so even worse. Maybe it is better on another Blender version. I didn't try that.

Comment: I tried putting the velocity to 0, and also removing the Effector, but the fluid level still rises above its initial position:

https://ibb.co/M7HWPB5

Comment: A good example, is this video footage here, the surface explodes, but the level remains as it is, the sea water doesnt rise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydWLkyMRfaU

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I use 3.3. Maybe it is a bug with 3.4.

Comment: I installed 3.3.1 today, to see how the fluid simulation works, and every 5 min Blender crashes... So I result in going back to 3.0. I tried to increase the resolution from 32 to 64, and that would take hours.

Comment: I added a bug report for 3.3.1, Once the object is set to effector>Guide. When I try to add keyframes in the timeline, Blender crashes.

Comment: developer from Blender, is working on the bug, I was emailed today. I don't know if this will help my current issue with the liquid rising though. 

https://developer.blender.org/T102257


I also posted a video of the problem in Blender artists

https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/5/9/0/5904221e394be5a20bb353b8b77198da695f62fa.m4v

Comment: Sounds good. Definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: Hi BlenderMaster. so Ill try the same thing with older version of Blender. So just to confirm, its a matter of velocity of the fluid-liquid set to 0, which doesn't allow it to rise, once been hit from the effector object?